# how to handle when show class call on runtime

Tags: angular, css, bootstrap-4, angular6

I need some help in angular. I want to add `abc` class when `show` class add and `abc` class hide when `show` class is hide I am using angular6 my condition are below please help me this

```
 <ul 
   [ngClass]="['show' === 'show' ? 'abc' : 'none-hightlight']" 
   *ngIf="cities.subcat.length>0" 
   class="first-sub-cat dropdown-menu">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use expression to validate if it's truthy you should be using object not array. More info on [angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

So in your case it would be something like this:

`{ 'acb': 'show' === 'show', 'none-hightlight': 'show' !== 'show' }`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ul 
   [ngClass]="{'show' === 'show' ? 'abc' : 'none-hightlight'}" 
   *ngIf="cities.subcat.length>0" 
   class="first-sub-cat dropdown-menu">
```